# Bootstrap Modal pop up displays only the first record.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to edit the records for that i am using twitter bootstrap modal pop up. I have a view-product page which contains a button to open a modal pop up but at present time the code i am using displays only one record on view-product page, but my database contains more records and further more if i click the edit icon it displays only the first record and also i want to know how to get the id on the next page i.e. editproducts.php I have spend much of the on this topic but did not solve it please help by giving suggestions. Thanks....

view-product.php

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
 <?php
 $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_product";
 $sql_q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
    {
    $productid=$row['pid'];
    $prodName= $row['product_name']; 
    $prodPrice= $row['product_price']; 
    $prodtype= $row['product_type'];
    $prodQty= $row['product_qty'];
    $description=$row['product_desc'];

 ?>
  <tr class="odd">
  <td class=" sorting_1"><?=$prodName?></td>
  <td class="center "><?=$prodPrice?></td>
  <td class="center "><?=$prodtype?></td>
  <td class="center "><?=$prodQty ?></td>
  <td class="center "><a class="btn btn-success" href="http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/simpliq2/table.html#"> <i class="fa fa-search-plus "></i> </a> <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDetail-<?=$productid?>" href="#myModalDetail"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/simpliq2/table.html#"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i> </a></td>

   </tr>
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDetail-<?=$productid?>">
 <?php require "edit_products.php"; ?>
  </div>

    <? } ?>
</tbody>
```

edit_products.php

```
<?php

 $productid=$_REQUEST[$productid];
  $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE pid='".$productid."'";
 $sql_q=mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q))
    {
        $productid=$row['pid'];
        $prodName= $row['product_name']; 
        $prodPrice= $row['product_price']; 
        $prodtype= $row['product_type'];
        $prodQty= $row['product_qty'];
        $description=$row['product_desc'];
    }
?>


 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Products Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <form role="form" name="Insertdb" method="post" action="Insert_code/edit-products.php">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Product Name</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input class="form-control" name="prodName" value="<?=$prodName ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Product Price</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input class="form-control" name="prodPrice" placeholder="Enter product price" value="<?=$prodPrice?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Product Type</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input class="form-control" name="productType" placeholder="Enter product type">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Product Quanity</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input class="form-control" name="productQty" placeholder="Enter product Quantity">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Upload Product Image</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input type="file" name="productImg">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Product Description</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="productDesc" rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <input name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Can you just give a hint how to pass a particular value to a modal pop up just for editing records.

Comment: When you display any record, you are using an id. So when you click on the edit, dynamically change the modal content to that of the product you want to edit. Use $('yourmodaldiv').html('new content') [jquery] to achieve this. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Modal only displays on edit button click so simply with the help of php can i pass id to the modal and open a particular record there.

Comment: In that case you can use the ajax call to contact the server with the id. Retrieve the required record and send it back. In the ajax.success() change the content of the modal using the .html().